# Dash: progress bar for reading files

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have seen this example of `Progress` & `Interval` components for displaying the progress in Dash:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

progress = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Interval(id="progress-interval", n_intervals=0, interval=500),
        dbc.Progress(id="progress"),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    [Output("progress", "value"), Output("progress", "children")],
    [Input("progress-interval", "n_intervals")],
)
def update_progress(n):
    # check progress of some background process, in this example we'll just
    # use n_intervals constrained to be in 0-100
    progress = min(n % 110, 100)
    # only add text after 5% progress to ensure text isn't squashed too much
    return progress, f"{progress} %" if progress >= 5 else ""
```

However, I cannot find any example that would actually show how to properly link the progress bar to some background process.

If, for example, I have a callback with a regular `for` loop, how can I show the progress of this `for` loop (i.e. if I'm on 10th element from 100, I want it to be displayed as 10% in the progress bar)?

Answer (score 3):

@Valeria, I created a tutorial on the progress bar and the spinner, which focuses on the formatting of the loaders. https://youtu.be/t1bKNj021do

But for the linking of the progress bar with a background process, this person was nice enough to create a sample app and code. https://github.com/tcbegley/dash-rq-demo

Comment: This "answer" is only links to something else (monetized you tube video??).  I'm voting for the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use a for-loop to update the progress bar.

But i had to:

1. Use `dcc.Interval` for when the dashboard should look for a new value.
2. Use threading for making the worker work independently and not blocking the dashboard.
3. Use Queue for thread safe communication between worker-thread and updating the progress bar.

Insted of using a global `progress_memory` and `Queue`, this could probably be grouped nicely using classes.

```py
import dash
import time
import threading
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from queue import Queue


progress_queue = Queue(1)
progress_memeory = 0


app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])


app.layout = dash.html.Div(children=[
    dash.html.H1(children='Test Progress Bar Using Loop'),
    dash.dcc.Interval(id='clock', interval=1000, n_intervals=0, max_intervals=-1),
    dbc.Progress(value=0, id="progress_bar"),
    dash.html.Button("Start Work", id='start_work', n_clicks=0)
])


@app.callback(
    [dash.Output("progress_bar", "value")],
    [dash.Input("clock", "n_intervals")])
def progress_bar_update(n):
    global progress_memeory
    if not progress_queue.empty():
        progress_bar_val = progress_queue.get()
        progress_memeory = progress_bar_val
    else:
        progress_bar_val = progress_memeory
    return(progress_bar_val,)
   

@app.callback([
    dash.Output("start_work", "n_clicks")],
    [dash.Input("start_work", "n_clicks")])
def start_bar(n):
    if n==0:
        return(0,)
    threading.Thread(target=start_work, args=(progress_queue,)).start()
    return(0,)


def start_work(output_queue):
    for i in range(101):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if output_queue.empty():
            output_queue.put(i)
    return(None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```